# How to get DNS Name in azure Virtual Machines - List All api?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to get the DNS Name in azure Virtual Machines - List All api in nodejs.
Please help me.

I checked this url [Virtual Machines - List All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall)
But DNS Name not availble in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the [FQDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn) for Azure VMs in the Azure portal. When you create a virtual machine (VM) in the Azure portal, a public IP resource for the virtual machine is automatically created. The FQDN actually is attached to the public IP resource for external accessing. So you will look for the public IP for the DNS name.

You can look up the API [Public IP Addresses - List All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/publicipaddresses/listall)

```
 "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "testlbl",
          "fqdn": "testlbl.westus.cloudapp.azure.com"
        },
```